# 1 auto_increment with 2 primary keys

Tags: mysql, primary-key, innodb, auto-increment, myisam

My intention is to create a table with 2 primary keys with one of those autoincrementing and the other specified when inserting and when I create a new field for this table it must start the recount if the not incremented primary key changes. This is what I had:

[image]

I have been able to get this changing the table engine to MyISAM. But there is something missing, the `auto_increment` does not start at 100 as it happened before.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE CONFIGURABLES(
    CODIEI2 INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CODIEI1 INTEGER,
    SKU VARCHAR(30),
    COLOR INTEGER,
    COLOR2 INTEGER,
    TALLA INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CODIEI PRIMARY KEY(CODIEI1,CODIEI2),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CODIEI1 FOREIGN KEY(CODIEI1) REFERENCES PRODUCTOS(ENTITY_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CCOLOR FOREIGN KEY(COLOR) REFERENCES COLORES(CODICOL) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CCOLOR2 FOREIGN KEY(COLOR2) REFERENCES COLORES(CODICOL) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CTALLA FOREIGN KEY(TALLA) REFERENCES TALLAS(CODITLL) ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=MyISAM;

ALTER TABLE CONFIGURABLES AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Is this happening because when the `auto_increment` value is different from the default number the engine must be set to InnoDB?

Is there a way to get it as I want?

**SOLUTION:**

The table can be back to InnoDB which is much better and there is no need for `auto_increment` on `CONFIGURABLES` table as this will be controlled when doing the insert.

```
CREATE TABLE CONFIGURABLES(
    CODIEI2 INTEGER,
    CODIEI1 INTEGER,
    SKU VARCHAR(30),
    COLOR INTEGER,
    COLOR2 INTEGER,
    TALLA INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CODIEI PRIMARY KEY(CODIEI1,CODIEI2),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CODIEI1 FOREIGN KEY(CODIEI1) REFERENCES PRODUCTOS(ENTITY_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CCOLOR FOREIGN KEY(COLOR) REFERENCES COLORES(CODICOL) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CCOLOR2 FOREIGN KEY(COLOR2) REFERENCES COLORES(CODICOL) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CTALLA FOREIGN KEY(TALLA) REFERENCES TALLAS(CODITLL) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

And when doing the insert do this:

```
BEGIN;
    SELECT @id := IFNULL(MAX(CODIEI2)+1,100) FROM CONFIGURABLES WHERE CODIEI1 = 10001 FOR UPDATE;
    INSERT INTO CONFIGURABLES
    (CODIEI1,CODIEI2,SKU,COLOR,COLOR2,TALLA)
    VALUES
    (10001,@id,'',4,2,2);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: _Two_ primary keys? That's _unpossible!_ :-)

Comment: To fulfill FK support you need InnoDB. On the other hand, composite auto_increment is supported only in MyISAM. So I guess you'll need to introduce surrogate PK, making your current one as just composite unique key

Comment: Are you sure the statement ALTER TABLE CONFIGURABLES AUTO_INCREMENT = 100; is executed? It looks good to me.

Comment: @Alma do How do I do that?

Comment: @massie Yes it does,  http://oi58.tinypic.com/4l0or4.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  BEGIN;
  SELECT @id := MAX(id)+1 FROM foo WHERE other = 123 FOR UPDATE;
  INSERT INTO foo
     (other, id, ...)
     VALUES
     (123, @id, ...);
  COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I needed to change MAX(id)+1 for IFNULL(MAX(id)+1,100) because it gave me error as when trying to do the insert for first time the select returned null. I've edited the answer with the solution. Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 0):

How do you insert your data? If you give CODIEI2 as a column and a value as well, this will overwrite the auto_increment.

Test in SQLFiddle:

Build schema:

```
CREATE TABLE CONFIGURABLES(
CODIEI2 INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
CODIEI1 INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT PK_CODIEI PRIMARY KEY(CODIEI2));

ALTER TABLE CONFIGURABLES AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;

INSERT INTO CONFIGURABLES ( CODIEI1 ) 
VALUES ( 1 );
```

Now overwriting the auto_increment:

```
INSERT INTO CONFIGURABLES ( CODIEI2, CODIEI1 ) 
VALUES ( 1, 2 );
```

Run SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM CONFIGURABLES;
```

Output:

```
CODIEI2 CODIEI1
1   2
100 1
```

Comment: I understand what you mean. This is not the problem, my insert looks like this "INSERT INTO CONFIGURABLES VALUES (NULL,10001,'',1,2,2);" . The auto_increment set as 100 works when the table engine is InnoDB (default in my case) but when I change it to MyISAM to be able to reset the auto_increment recount, this is not working. Thanks for your time and help btw :)